# Cutting out Specific Strings in Matlab

Tags: matlab

Hi I have a data table that has values of either `Y`, `N`, or `U` in Matlab called data2.

I want to keep everything that has `Y` and cut out everything.

I used strcmp to find `N` and successfully cut out the rows with 'N'. However, I want to get rid of both `U` and `N`. I tried using | to signify an or inside the cmpstr but it did not work.

```
rowIdx = strcmp('N' , data2{:, 1});
data2(rowIdx, :) = [];
```

Only cut out the `N` even with the `|` sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search for `'N'` and `'U'` separately and then sum the logical arrays. Since an element of the first column cannot be `'N'` and `'U'` at the same time you will end up with an array where you will have `1` for the rows containing `'N'` or `'U'` and `0` otherwise.

So the code would be :

```matlab
rowIdx_N = strcmp('N' , data2{:, 1});
rowIdx_U = strcmp('U' , data2{:, 1});
rowIdx = rowIdx_N|rowIdx_U;% Performs OR operation on logical array
data2(rowIdx, :) = [];
```

Comment: When I tried this, they said that "A table row subscript must be a numeric array containing real positive integers, a logical array, a character vector, a string
array, or a cell array of character vectors."

Comment: @MoanaLisa I fixed the issue `rowIdx` was not a logical array, it should work now

Comment: Right! Thanks for the assistance!

Comment: @MoanaLisa Happy to help. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of regular expressions and extract only the rows that match a specified pattern (`'y'`in your case). This has the big advantage that it is much more general and can be used to search for any pattern. Also explicit deletion of found matches is not necessary.

```
% test table, just for demo since you did not provide any data
t = {'u', 'Y', 'h', 'f'; 'f', 'h', 'h', 'e'; 'g', 'd', 'y', 'n'};
t = cell2table(t)

pattern = 'y'; % any regular expression
str = t{:, :};

found = regexp(str, pattern) % or regexpi() for case insensitivity

[r,c] = find(~cellfun(@isempty,found));
t(unique(r),:) % matching rows of table t
```

`unique()` in the last line is needed in case multiple matches are found in a single line, which would otherwise result in multiple occurences of this single line in the output.

Comment: Can you clarify more about the [r,c] part? What does that mean?

Comment: `r` is my variable for rows and `c`for columns.  `[r, c] = function(...)`, where `[r, c]`is on the left of an assignment means, that 2 values will be returned by the function (`find()` in this case). See also https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/275599-function-return-multiple-variables  This captures the row and column indices of all cells in `found`which are not empty (=match the pattern).

Comment: Or check https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function.html for the  example `Function with multiple outputs`.